# Do you lose Static Typing ability while using a #DEFINE statement?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor, static-typing

I seem to be losing static typing ability when defining,

```
#define myAppDelegate (WorkClockAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

To do this,

```
[myAppDelegate doSomething];
```

Xcode doesn't know what **doSomething** is, although it will compile and run fine as long as I know what I'm doing, and **doSomething** actually exists on myAppDelegate!

Is there any way I can overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't lose it, no -- you are probably omitting an `#import`, or the order of `#import`s may be wrong.

> Is there any way I can overcome this?

Just use a function:

```
WorkClockAppDelegate * myAppDelegate() {
  // TODO add error checking
  return (WorkClockAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

or a method:

```
+ (WorkClockAppDelegate *)workClockAppDelegate {
  // TODO add error checking
  return (WorkClockAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

to introduce type safety.

although you could use an `extern` variable, that's not very safe.

using `#define` is not a good solution, imo.

Comment: Thank you @Justin, I will be using the method approach. Somehow seems more elegant. But is there really any reason why #define would not be a good solution?

Comment: @nmdias you're welcome. a: it reads like a global variable, could cause compilation errors. it's not clear, or what many people would expect. there's no need for any of that, and there are superior alternatives (imo). the bonus with a function or method is that you can hide stuff and reduce your build times -- that `#define` could require clients to `#import` unnecessarily.